# Data Structure for uniquely storing links

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

As part of building a web crawler I have extracted links for visits by the crawler.

What kind of data structure would be suitable for storing each URL with a unique identifier so I before visiting a page I can test to see if the page has already been visited.

Comment: how about a list, or every other structure you can search through. it's not like you're going to have millions of sites visited

Comment: well that's uncalled for

Comment: A `Hashtable` or you could create your own

Comment: A [Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd412081.aspx) springs to mind (C#)

Comment: @WinCoder might be i'm a little rude, but honestly, what have you tried before posting the question?

Comment: I am self learned programmer and as such have little idea on where to start in the matters of algorithms and data structures.

Comment: Are you coding in C# or Java? Your question has both tags associated with it.

Comment: @DuncanJones Just wanted a language agnostic answer.

Comment: @WinCoder As you wish - I've corrected the tags accordingly. However, I suspect you'll get more *practical* answers if you explain what language you've started writing the web crawler in. Then the answers can be directly used in your code.

Comment: @WinCoder You're not self educated unless you've taken the steps to educate yourself. Learning about basic datastructures and algorithms is a *basic* part of the programmer's craft. Go find yourself a book on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

An approach: consider unique-identifier is page/url title or some unique hash caculated from `url`, for example:

> **URL:**
>   http://stackoverflow.com /questions/18102087/data-structure-for-uniqurly-storing-links
>
> **Id:** 18102087 OR UNIQUE-HASH (MD5 etc)
>
> **Root:** http://stackoverflow.com
>
> **Other URLs:** Root/questions/tagged/java, Root/questions/18102124/mysql-database-using-matlab

**Data-structure :**

```
Map [ROOT-URL, Map[ID, URL]]
```

**Fetch/Read :**

- Given URL, extract ROOT and ID (a string parsing/regex function)
- Lookup ROOT, and LOOKUP ID in returned map

**Get all URL of a ROOT:**

- Given URL, extract ROOT and ID
- Lookup ROOT

**Benefit:**

- Grouping on root or base URL, can be used for various purpose (say fix-deep structure)
- Lessen Hash colisions

**Cons:**

- Memory, maintaining extra ROOT string (say millions times). One `Map` approach would have only ID and URL
- Two lookups instead of one in comparison to single Map approach, but that should be fine as it is `HashMap`

Comment: Just a thought - the main map can be modified and instead of a map with id-url pairs can store an object that keeps this id-url map but also something like a number of occurrences of this (root)url. So the map can be limited in size and the rarest visited root can be dropped out of the map to be replaced by a new one. This is in case the map's size needs to be limited ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) is the way to go. In this case each url (or string) is a unique identifier. You can also implement an IEqualityComparer for custom comparison.